# Onclick functionality in android

Tags: java, android

### I am trying to launch new tabactivity on click from one tab activity

*I am able to load the things to first activity...... but `onclick` of Photo button as shown in one of the class in am getting error as shown in the log cat ....*

**How can i resolve this**

**Any ideas**

**AndroidTabRestaurantDescListView.java**

```
public class AndroidTabRestaurantDescListView extends TabActivity {

    // TabSpec Names
        private static final String INBOX_SPEC = "Rating";
        private static final String OUTBOX_SPEC = "Price";
        private static final String PROFILE_SPEC = "Distance";

        Button Photos;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Photos=(Button) findViewById(R.id.PhotoButton); 

            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

            // Inbox Tab
            TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(INBOX_SPEC);
            Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            inboxSpec.setIndicator(INBOX_SPEC);
            // Tab Content
            inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);

            // Outbox Tab
            TabSpec PriceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(OUTBOX_SPEC);
            Intent PriceIntent = new Intent(this, PriceDescriptionActivity.class);
            PriceSpec .setIndicator(OUTBOX_SPEC);
            PriceSpec.setContent(PriceIntent);

            // Profile Tab
            TabSpec DistanceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(PROFILE_SPEC);
            Intent DistanceIntent = new Intent(this, DistanceDiscriptionActivity.class);
            DistanceSpec .setIndicator(PROFILE_SPEC); 
            DistanceSpec.setContent(DistanceIntent);

            // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
            tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec); 
            tabHost.addTab(PriceSpec); 
            tabHost.addTab(DistanceSpec); 

            //Set the current value tab to default first tab
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

            //Setting custom height for the tabs
            final int height = 45;
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = height;
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = height;
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = height;




            Photos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent PhotoIntent=new Intent(AndroidTabRestaurantDescListView.this,AndroidTabRestaurantDescImageListView.class);
                    startActivity(PhotoIntent);

                }
            });

        }

}
```

**manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.project.findmybuffet.AndroidTabRestaurantDescListView" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.project.findmybuffet.SingleItemView" >
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantDesc"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.project.findmybuffet.RestaurantPhotos"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.project.findmybuffet.DistanceDiscriptionActivity">
        </activity>    

        <activity
            android:name="com.project.findmybuffet.PriceDescriptionActivity">
        </activity> 

        <activity
            android:name="com.project.findmybuffet.MainActivity">
        </activity> 

        <activity
            android:name="com.project.findmybuffet.AndroidTabRestaurantDescImageListView">
        </activity> 

        <activity
            android:name="com.project.findmybuffet.DistanceDiscriptionOnlyImageActivity">
        </activity> 

        <activity
            android:name="com.project.findmybuffet.PriceDescriptionOnlyImageActivity">
        </activity> 

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Log::**

```
09-28 12:12:40.415: I/MemoryCache(1222): MemoryCache will use up to 8.0MB
09-28 12:12:40.875: D/dalvikvm(1222): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 313K, 50% free 2967K/5895K, external 2130K/2137K, paused 119ms
09-28 12:12:40.925: I/MemoryCache(1222): cache size=47000 length=1
09-28 12:12:41.105: I/MemoryCache(1222): cache size=111500 length=2
09-28 12:12:41.245: I/MemoryCache(1222): cache size=179940 length=3
09-28 12:12:41.285: I/MemoryCache(1222): cache size=237060 length=4
09-28 12:12:48.255: D/AndroidRuntime(1222): Shutting down VM
09-28 12:12:48.255: W/dalvikvm(1222): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial/com.project.findmybuffet.AndroidTabRestaurantDescImageListView}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial/com.project.findmybuffet.RatingDescriptionOnlyImageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial/com.project.findmybuffet.RatingDescriptionOnlyImageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.resolveActivityInfo(ActivityThread.java:1457)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:277)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at com.project.findmybuffet.AndroidTabRestaurantDescImageListView.onCreate(AndroidTabRestaurantDescImageListView.java:44)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-28 12:12:48.287: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is very descriptive:

> Unable to find explicit activity class {com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial/com.project.findmybuffet.RatingDescriptionOnlyImageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

And the answer is: no, you haven't declared that activity in your manifest. You've got plenty of other activities in your manifest, but not that one.

As well as simply fixing this by adding the activity to your manifest, I suggest you take a step back and think about how you could have figured this out for yourself. Did you read the log file carefully? Did you somehow miss the error message I quoted? (Always look for "cause" exception messages.) It's really important to learn how to diagnose things for yourself - so see if you can work out why you didn't quite get there this time, so that you can improve for next time.

Comment: 09-28 12:24:18.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1265): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 12:24:18.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):  at com.project.findmybuffet.RatingDescriptionOnlyImageActivity$DownloadJSON.onPostExecute(RatingDescriptionOnlyImageActivity.java:95)

Comment: @smriti2: That's now a different problem, which you should try to fix for yourself and then ask about in a different question if necessary. (But look at RatingDescriptionOnlyImageActivity line 95, and see if you can work out what might be null. Use the debugger if it helps.)

Comment: @smriti2: Because you're trying to dereference a null reference. Again, you should try to fix that yourself.

Comment: Solved the errors completely ....... I will be more carefull in diagonising the errors ..... thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurred because you haven't declared RatingDescriptionOnlyImageActivity this activity in your manifest. You have declared all other activities but not this one. So please take a look in manifest file and check package name proper and then write this activity into your manifest file. Your problem will be solved for sure.